# Change multiple default filters based on the value chosen from a dropdown property control: Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

how can I change multiple default filters based on the value chosen from a dropdown property control?

How do I achieve this functionality?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's a little unclear what you're asking. is the question: "how can I change filtering schemes using a dropdown property control?" or "how can I change multiple filters based on the value chosen from a dropdown property control?" further, please edit your question to clarify it

Comment: hi Niko, it is how can I change multiple default filters based on the value chosen from a dropdown property control?

Comment: great, I can definitely help you with that :) gimme a few to figure out the code. may I suggest to please update your question to reflect so that others can find it in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's not a lot of detail in your question, so I'm making a lot of assumptions here, most importantly that **you are dealing with ListBox filters**; this code will not work with other filter types. this is the dataset I'm using:

```
NAME    DEPARTMENT
alice   marketing
bob     sales
charley sales
dave    engineering
```

1. in the analysis, add a **Text Area** and insert a **Dropdown Property Control**
2. click **New...** to create a new **Document Property** called `Department`, which will be a **String** and contains the default value `sales`
3. **Set property value through: Unique values in column**, and choose the `Department` column
4. click **Script...** and in the dialog, choose **Execute the script selected below**, then hit **New...**
5. give the script a name like `ChangeFilter`. **Add...** a **Script parameter**
6. call the **Script parameter** `department_name`, set it to **String**, then select **Property:**, and finally click **Select Property...** to set it to our `department` **Document Property**
7. paste in the following code snippet:

```
# import the ListBoxFilter class
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import ListBoxFilter

# locate the data table and grab the filter collection
dt = Document.Data.Tables["Data Table"]
filters = Document.FilteringSchemes.DefaultFilteringSchemeReference[dt]

# repeat the below lines for any other filters you would like to change

# choose the filter we are interested in
f = filters["department"].As[ListBoxFilter]()

# unset "IncludeAllValues" or nothing we change will matter
f.IncludeAllValues = False
# set the value we are interested in
f.SetSelection(department_name)
```

8. accept all dialogs until you're back at your analysis, and test.

Comment: Niko, perfect! This is what I was looking for. Really appreciate your detailed response.